# Summation of logarithmic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I am solving a recurrence relation and it requires me to sum the following series upto $\log{n}$ terms -
     $1/\log(n) + 1/\log(n/2) + 1/\log(n/4)$.....

The base in each term is $2$. Any help on how to proceed?

Comment: what have u tried? Also, is $n$ a power of $2$?

Answer (score 1):

For every $n$, one considers considers 
$$s(n)=\sum_{k\geqslant0}\frac1{\log_2(n/2^k)},
$$ where the sum is over every $k$ such that $2^k\lt n$ and $\log_2$ is the logarithm with base $2$. One cannot hope any explicit formula valid for every $n$ but note that, for every $i$, 
$$s(2^i)=\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}1/(i-k)=H_i,$$ 
where $H_i$ denotes the $i$th harmonic number. Since $H_i\sim\log i$ (natural logarithm), this yields $s(2^i)\sim\log i$ when $i\to\infty$. This suggests the asymptotics
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n)}{\log\log_2 n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n)}{\log\log n}=1.
$$
Unfortunately, unless a more precise definition of $s(n)$ is provided, it seems that the sequence $(s(n))$ does not converge due to the jumps in the summation when $n$ passes a power of $2$. For example, for every $i$,
$$
s(1+2^i)=\sum_{k=0}^{i}1/\log_2(2^{i-k}+2^{-k})\geqslant1/\log_2(1+2^{-i})\sim2^i\log2,
$$
and $2^i\log2\gg\log\log(1+2^i)$. And actually,
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n)}{\log\log n}=1,\qquad\limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{s(n)}{\log\log n}=+\infty.
$$